# Create Custom shapes in Android

Tags: android, gradient, shapes

I am looking for some tutorial or some reference which can help me to create some custom shapes like below mentioned shapes.

[image: Shape 1]

[image: Shape 2]

I have tried creating shape using standard shape in android xml , but i am not able to find a appropriate solutions for it.

It would be good help if some one can explain how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: I would go with a 9-patch image, if you are going to use it for a button background and resize for different screen sizes.

Comment: seems to be right approach of creating 9 patch image

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.